# Flex layout with images resize unevenly in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox, zurb-foundation

I have a layout that is utilizing flex to hold images of varying sizes together. 
However, when I resize the browser in Firefox the images don't scale evenly.

I have read a lot of posts about what causes the issue, but I am having a difficult time finding the solution for my particular scenario in the sea of information.  Anyone have any ideas?

Image of where the breaks are happening in firefox.

[image]

```
*{box-sizing: border-box;}

.container{
  max-width: 1360px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img{
  border:2px solid white;
}

.flex-row {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-column{
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1360px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .flex-column, .flex-row{
    display: block;
  }
  img{
    width: 100%;
  }
}


<div class="container">
<div class="flex-row row">
  <div class="flex-column">
    <div><img src="https://placehold.it/548x227"></div>
    <div><img src="https://placehold.it/548x459"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-column">
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div><img src="https://placehold.it/812x459"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row bug">
      <div><img src="https://placehold.it/406x227"></div>
          <div><img src="https://placehold.it/406x227"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-row row">
  <div><img src="https://placehold.it/812x459"></div>
  <div><img src="https://placehold.it/548x459"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is a link to the code:  https://codepen.io/enigmas2/pen/zZYPJj

Comment: I think it might be because neither `container` nor `flex-row` have heights, whereas your `flex-column` class has a height of `100%`, but, again, its parents doesn't have a height. Try giving them specific heights! The images, if made responsive, however, will end up getting cropped or not maintaining their proper proportions. This is unavoidable, though.

Comment: I mean, the issue you're experiencing is because your `img` elements are set to `width: 100%` and -- implicitly I believe -- `height: auto`, which means their `width` will always fill up the containing block/parent/element, but in order for the `img` to maintain its natural dimensions its height will naturally shrink and leave a gap.

Comment: I will tinker with the heights.

Comment: Adding heights doesn't make a change in Firefox.

Comment: have u made sure ur stles don't clash/override one another?? as soon as i get like 20 free minutes i'll quickly whip something up. it might be a bug. i just discovered another bug with firefox so i wouldn't b surprised

Comment: I would be so grateful if you could. This has been a thorn in my side for weeks.

Comment: Np. just dealing with my ISP atm. then gotta make a phone call to a client. and then i'll hop on it

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: can you provide me a link to the codepen again? for some reason it won't let me open up your codepen or when it does it's missing the media query and what not

Comment: https://codepen.io/enigmas2/details/zZYPJj/

Comment: Sorry that was me. The media query isn't needed. The layout needs to scale down.

Comment: k, well, i got the image-resize thing fixed. the issue, as i stated before, was of course that the images were auto-resizing while maintaining their proportions, so even though the images were taking up less room, their containers were still covering the entire area. so what i had to do was was simply use the `background` property (set to center/cover) instead of `<img/>` elements. https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/aJzWvz?editors=1100 however, it's bugged out now once the media query takes places. i'll fix it when i'm done eating if you can provide me with the original codepen

Comment: Sorry about that! I'll fix and get you the original

Comment: hm.. if the media query isn't needed, what do you mean by the layout needs to scale down?

Comment: in that codepen i provided, you can see what's happening by looking at the left image in the very bottom row. what i've done is set the background color to purple. the image resizes, but the container remains the same height

Comment: To clarify it begins breaking apart when it hits tablet size 768px I have to get it looking good there. I meant to say to test I just use a chrome dev tools.

Comment: Firstly, you are the bomb. Second, I love the graphics lol! Finally, that is a beautiful eloquent solution! I can't thank you enough!

Comment: I will work that into my site and check this as answered :)

Comment: hahah thanks. yeah soft drink logos are awesome. i don't even drink em cuz theyre so bad for u lol, but some of the logos r really nice. was using a a diff pepsi one that was super dope but switched it for the sake of clarity since it had a white border. yeah, the solution should work. i know what you want to do, so i'm just gon quickly build one from scratch. i don't even need the pen. i'll post it below and u can mark it as the solution once i do :P

Comment: That would be amazing thank you!! I hear you on the Soda. I drink it like a dessert every once in a while lol

Comment: wow. k. i'm pretty sure firefox's flex-box is bugged out. columns don't seem to work properly. despite that, i wrote a version that works of what i imagine you wanted. the potential issue is that a lot of elements have fixed heights. [here it is.](http://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/mWywaZ) i'll post it below too. what are you building this for??

Comment: I'm building it for the launch of a University park for Alumni and students. The mobile version is more app like so that I coded separately. This needs to look good down to mobile breakpoint.

Comment: I seriously cannot thank you enough! You are fantastic!

Comment: cool! well, best of luck with that :) hahah, no problema. you are my good deed for the day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm pretty sure firefox's flex-box is bugged out. columns don't seem to work properly.

despite that, you can kind of achieve the same thing using the `float` property. it took more code than i expected, however.

a potential issue is that a lot of elements have fixed heights. as i mentioned before, too, another issue with doing it this way is that images will be cropped. (notice the ikea and cheerio logos. it's because their widths far outweighs their heights).

[here is a codepen.](http://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/mWywaZ)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

  #container {
    width: 75vw;
    height: 1145px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  
    #row-one {
      width: 75vw;
      display: block;
    }
    
      #left-column {
        width: 40.294117647058823529411764705882%;
        height: 686px;
        float: left;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      
        #top-left-image {
          width: 100%;
          height: 227px;
          background: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/cNGG2SswaKo/maxresdefault.jpg') center/cover;
        }
        
        #middle-left-image {
          width: 100%;
          height: 459px;
          background: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/8b/da/34/8bda3460f271a77a54b4cfc08583b1fc.jpg') center/cover;
        }
      
      #right-column {
        width: 59.705882352941176470588235294118%;
        height: 686px;
        float: right;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      
        #top-right-image {
          width: 100%;
          height: 459px;
          background: url('http://cdn.designcrowd.com.s3.amazonaws.com/blog/Famous-Purple-Logos/1-famous-purple-logos.png') center/cover;
        }
        
        #right-column-row {
          width: 100%;
        }
        
          #middle-middle-image {
            width: 50%;
            height: 227px;
            float: left;
            background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/Ikea_logo.svg/1024px-Ikea_logo.svg.png') center/cover;
          }
          
          #middle-right-image {
            width: 50%;
            height: 227px;
            float: right;
            background: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/f9/bd/c8/f9bdc85df698cd33535f3517659b9c03.jpg') center/cover;
          }
    
    #row-two {
      width: 75vw;
      height: 459px;
      display: block;
    }
    
      #bottom-left-image {
        width: 59.705882352941176470588235294118%;
        height: 459px;
        float: left;
        background: url('http://logok.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Sprite-logo-2014.png') center/cover;
      }
    
      #bottom-right-image {
        width: 40.294117647058823529411764705882%;
        height: 459px;
        float: right;
        background: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/58/6f/a9/586fa96b662feb46fd10d179a3f5308d.jpg') center/cover;
      }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  
  #left-column, #right-column, #right-column-row, #bottom-left-image, #bottom-right-image {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
  
  .some-images {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="a.css">
  <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="row-one">
      <div id="left-column">
        <div class="not-all-images" id="top-left-image"></div>
        <div class="not-all-images" id="middle-left-image"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="right-column">
        <div class="not-all-images" id="top-right-image"></div>
        <div id="right-column-row">
          <div id="middle-middle-image"></div>
          <div id="middle-right-image"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div>
    <div id="row-two">
      <div class="not-all-images" id="bottom-left-image"></div>
      <div class="not-all-images" id="bottom-right-image"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```